# Intervention - Resize - Quality

Tags: php, image, image-processing, intervention

I am trying to resize images from 3000 * 4000 px with a size of 7 MB to images of height 650px. With intervention I am using the following steps.

```
Image::configure(array('driver' => 'gd'));
$img = Image::make($imgName);
$img->resize(null,650, function ($constraint) {
  $constraint->aspectRatio();
  $constraint->upsize();
});
$img->encode('jpg', 100);
$img->save($img_path, 100);
```

But the images that gets saved looks a bit blurred. Would be great any one could direct me with the correct steps.

Thanks
Lynn